how to concatenate change files
I am interested in simplifying a tex.ch file to make the code more portable (a rather theoretical endeavour); but I am not sure about how to do it "correctly", from a technical viewpoint.
Which one is better: (1) commenting the @x,@y,@z construct of the original change file, or (2) preparing a new one changing the change?
Let's say, for the sake of this argument, that I mean to keep the original banner, but the change file I mean to circumvent does something along these lines:

[2] Change the banner line
@x
known as `\TeX' [cf.~Stanford Computer Science report CS1027,
November 1984].

@d banner=='This is TeX, Version 3.14159265' {printed when \TeX\ starts}
@y
known as `\TeX' [cf.~Stanford Computer Science report CS1027,
November 1984].

@d banner=='This is MyTeX.'
@z

There is no way, afaics, to recover the original banner after this change. Am I right?
I do mean to automatize the changes through tie, but I'm unsure of how to do it.

Can you remove the bit about the law? I'm pretty sure we're not allowed to have questions that request legal advice for ... er ... legal reasons.

I have no idea why this has been nominated for closure on the grounds it isn't within the scope of the site. Unless the legal concern is it, but I somehow doubt that's so.

just removed the objectionable "legal" part...

Change files are applied sequentially: once one is applied, the 'old' information is gone and what you have is a new file which has the updated content. As such, whilst one can apply multiple .ch files in order, you can't 'go back' to undo a previous .ch file other than by applying a reverting change explicitly.

but then, nothing prevents me to put a change file before the "offending" change file, to make it fail, and then restore the original one in my own change files after the "offending" one, correct?

@jarnosc The process will stop at the first failure, so you'll never get to output here
